# T-SQL query to SQLITE

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query but struggling to convert it to SQLite for android, I have same table names, field name, table structure and relationship, any help will be appreciated, below is the query

```
SELECT
   F.fieldID,F.name,F.description,F.sizeHA,F.sizeA
   ,F.owner,F.annualRent,F.latitude,F.longitude
   ,F.Farm_farmID,F.isActive,F.deactivationDate,F.areas,
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(culture)) FROM Usages 
          WHERE Field_fieldID = F.fieldID
          AND YEAR(date) = (SELECT TOP 1 YEAR(date) FROM Usages 
                            ORDER BY Date DESC)
   ) as UsageCount
   ,(SELECT TOP 1 u.culture FROM Usages u WHERE u.Field_fieldID = F.fieldID 
      ORDER BY u.date desc) as culture
   ,(SELECT TOP 1 u.sort FROM Usages u WHERE u.Field_fieldID = F.fieldID 
      ORDER BY u.date desc) as sort 
FROM Fields as F INNER JOIN Usages s on s.Field_fieldID = F.fieldID 
GROUP BY F.fieldID,F.name,F.description,F.sizeHA,F.sizeA
,F.owner,F.annualRent,
F.latitude,F.longitude,F.Farm_farmID,F.isActive,F.deactivationDate,F.areas
```

Comment: `struggling to convert it` - what does this mean?  You get errors?  Compiler errors or runtime?  What happens?

Comment: @Simon I am not familiar with sqllite so struggling to get the syntax right and the alternatives for TOP keyword,get Year from Date etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace usage of `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ...
```

with the [LIMIT clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby):

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 1
```

Furthermore, there is no `YEAR` function. If your dates are stored in one of the [supported date formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), use `strftime` to get the year as a four-digit string:

```
strftime('%Y', date)
```